# Can't get response after click on a link using jquery/ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've a link in my php page. Which I want to send a `id` request to server. But it doesn't response correctly. Actually, I've got two pages.

a. **users.php**

b. **user_update.php**

So I'm trying a send a request to the server using jquery/ajax by **user id** from **users.php** page to **user_update.php** for update the details and get back the successful result to **user.php page**.

The code is look like this:

```
<div id="edit_user_details"><a href="#">Edit Details</a></div>   
<script>
$('#edit_user_details').click(function() {
    id = <?php echo $uid; ?>
    $.ajax({        
        url: edit_user_details.php,
        type: post,             
        data: id;
        success: function(response) {
            $('#edit_user_result').html(response);          
        }            
    });
});
</script>
```

But it's not working properly. is there anything I'm missing because of I'm new learning of Jquery/Ajax. :)

**Update:**

I'm requesting this `id` in php `while loop`. It's look like this..

```
while($search_result =  mysql_fetch_array($getUser)){
 $uid = (int) $search_result['user_id'];    
 <div id="edit_user_details"><a href="#">Edit Details</a></div>   
 }

<script>
$('#edit_user_details').click(function() {
    id = <?php echo $uid; ?>;
    $.ajax({        
            url: 'edit_user_details.php',
            type: 'post',             
            data: {'id' : id},
            success: function(response) {
            $('#edit_user_result').html(response);          
            }            
    });
});
</script>
```

Is it wrong ? What I'm trying is... I want to update user details base on their id. So what need to do for this ?

Comment: srry i dun understand your sending of ID OF WHAT ?

Comment: is that a typo? or is that `type: post` missing quotations

Comment: FYI, if you're using Firefox you must surely install Firebug. A lot of information will be shown then and there itself in the Firebug's console.

Comment: @M.chaudhry In user details page I've a lots of user which I want to update their details by their `id`. So that I place this `id` to jquery. I need to send this id to another page and in another page I need to process it. After successfully process it's should be get response to main page.

Comment: @asprin I saw Firfox consol log. I can't see any request is call by jquery/ajax.

Comment: Did you include the `jquery` library also?

Comment: @asprin I'm using this one..`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a unique id in loop or create a function and calll it onclick like

```
<?php while($search_result =  mysql_fetch_array($getUser)){
 $uid = (int) $search_result['user_id']; ?>   
 <div id="edit_user_details"><a href="#" onClick="myfunc('<?php echo $uid;?>')">Edit Details</a></div>   
<?php }?>

<script>
function myfunc(id) {
    id = id;
    $.ajax({        
            url: 'db_search.php',
            type: 'post',             
            data: {'id' : id},
            success: function(response) {
            $('#edit_user_result').html(response);          
            }            
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hello Rakesh did you saw my update question. I've another problem.

Comment: you need to make every id unique or call a function onclick check my updated answer

Comment: Well, In first row i get the response but another row i don't see the response. I'm outputting the result in `<div id="edit_user_result"></div>` this div.

Comment: check you have $uid value in all div by inspect element or debug code with console

Comment: Yes, it's showing the uid value. but I'm asking when edit second row then I don't get the success result but it firbug consol it showing success result.

Comment: then you need to check where you have success response id exist?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51853/discussion-between-babu-and-rakesh-sharma)

Answer (score 0):

- you should end your id initialization with a semi-colon;

  `id = <?php echo $uid; ?>;`
- Check the correct way of using ajax in this example: [Demo ajax using JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#entry-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Make changes as shown below and try again..

1: Add 'post' in type.

2: Add ''edit_user_details.php' in url

3: Add semicolon at the end here

```
<?php echo $uid; ?>;
```

4: take your id as shown in below code

Updated code :-

```
<script>
$('#edit_user_details').click(function() {
    id = <?php echo $uid; ?>;
    $.ajax({        
            url: 'edit_user_details.php',
            type: 'post',             
            data: {'id' : id},
            success: function(response) {
            $('#edit_user_result').html(response);          
            }            
    });
});
</script>
```

For more information :-

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#entry-examples

Comment: This is wrong `data: {id : id};` It should be `data: {'id' : id},`

Comment: @Neel How do i receive this id value to user_update.php page ? Using `$id = $_POST['id']` ?

Comment: what problem you are facing @Babu? and what currently ur getting in id? make alert there

Comment: @Neel I"m updating my question..please wait a sec.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51851/discussion-between-babu-and-neel)

Answer (score 0):

i think you are not declaring var id before

try

```
<div id="edit_user_details"><a href="#">Edit Details</a></div>   
<script>
$('#edit_user_details').click(function() {
  var id = <?php echo $uid; ?>;
    $.ajax({        
        url: edit_user_details.php,
        type: post,             
        data: [id:id],
        success: function(response) {
            $('#edit_user_result').html(response);          
        }            
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hello M chaudhry can you please see my update question ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your url inside $.ajax. If you are sending your data to user_update.php then your code should be as follows :

```
<script>
$('#edit_user_details').click(function() {
id = <?php echo $uid; ?>
$.ajax({        
    url: user_update.php,
    type: post,             
    data: id,
    success: function(response) {
        $('#edit_user_result').html(response);          
    }            
    });
 });
</script>
```

Just change your url to user_update.php and put a comma(,) after data:id in the place of semicolon(;).

Answer (score 0):

This code will works fine for what you need and with less lines, assuming that the PHP var $uid will be processed on loading the page:

```
<div id="edit_user_details"><a href="#">Edit Details</a></div>   
<script>
$('#edit_user_details').click(function() {
    $.get('edit_user_details.php', 'id=<?php echo $uid; ?>', function(response){
          $('#edit_user_result').html(response);
      });
});
</script>
```